# How to disable on page search in Mozilla firefox

Tags: firefox

Is there a way to disable on-page search in Firefox?

What I mean, is that Firefox has a behavior that when your cursor is not in some active text area, or input it searches for a word within page.

I find this very annoying, I am more used to search text on the page with shortcut CTRL + f on demand.

Looked through about:config , but couldn't find anything aproporiate.

```
firefox-esr   52.3.0esr-1~deb8u2 on Devuan x64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Preferences->Advanced->General, uncheck "Search for text when you start typing".

Alternatively, in about:config, set `accessibility.typeaheadfind` to `false`.